# Proper way of using React.Provider in Typescript to update user context

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm still wrapping my head on the way how Typescript is written. But my Typescript React web app wont build because I am getting the following:

```js
Type '({ user: { id: any; }; } | Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ user: { id: any; }; }>>)[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ user: { id: any; }; }'
index.d.ts(338, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<{ user: { id: any; }; }>'
```

How to solve this? I feel that I'm using it incorrectly, and my setup is in a mess. How to improve this? I'm learning. Any tips are welcome.

### My setup as follows:

In `_app.tsx`:

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import UserContext, { UserDefault } from "@contexts/UserContext";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(UserDefault);

  return (
    <>
        <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}> // <--- `value` giving error above
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </UserContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

In `@contexts/UserContext.ts`:

```js
import { createContext } from "react";
export const UserDefault = {
  user: {
    id: null,
  }
};
const UserContext = createContext(UserDefault);
export default UserContext;
```

### If I wanna update the user context, I create a hook:

In `hooks/useGetUserContext.ts`:

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from "@contexts/UserContext";

const useGetUserContext = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
  return {
    userContext: user,
    setUserContext: setUser,
  };
};

export default useGetUserContext;
```

And then after login success, I update the user context:

```js
import useGetUserContext from "@hooks/useGetUserContext";

const Login = (props) => {
    const { userContext, setUserContext } = useGetUserContext();
    setUserContext({
      user: userObject
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to it

```
value={{user, setUser}}>
```